# Pyspark code to load dataframe to AWS dax cluster

Tags: python, pyspark, dax, aws-glue, aws-dax

I am trying to load data to aws dax from glue. What is the best way to achieve this?

Note: I have loaded data using lambda function by making use of amazondax module. But now, I am trying to load dataframe to dax cluster using glue